# Ajax call every minute

Tags: javascript, php, ajax

I have a folder watcher that i want to be called once a minute, but i cant get it working.

The folder watcher will return `1` or `0`. If `data == 1` then the page will be refreshed, if `0` wait a min and run again.

Can someone help me to find out whats wrong?

The script:

```
     <script type="text/javascript"> 
function timedRefresh(timeoutPeriod) {
setTimeout(Update(),timeoutPeriod);
}

function Update() {
            $.ajax({
            url: "checkfolder.php", 
            type: "POST",


            success: function (data) {

                if(data == "1"){
                   //Page will be updated
                }
                else{
                    timedRefresh(60000);
                }

            }
        });

        }

</script>
```

Heres the checkfolder.php:

```
    <?php
// Configuration ///////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
$host ='xxxx';
$port = 21;
$user = 'xxxx';
$pass = 'xxxx';
$remote_dir = '../img/uploads/';
$cache_file = 'ftp_cache';

// Main Run Program ////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////

// Connect to FTP Host
$conn = ftp_connect($host, $port) or die("Could not connect to {$host}\n");

// Login
if(ftp_login($conn, $user, $pass)) {

  // Retrieve File List
  $files = ftp_nlist($conn, $remote_dir);

  // Filter out . and .. listings
  $ftpFiles = array();
  foreach($files as $file)
  {
    $thisFile = basename($file);
    if($thisFile != '.' && $thisFile != '..') {
      $ftpFiles[] = $thisFile;
    }
  }

  // Retrieve the current listing from the cache file
  $currentFiles = array();
  if(file_exists($cache_file))
  {
    // Read contents of file
    $handle = fopen($cache_file, "r");
    if($handle)
    {
      $contents = fread($handle, filesize($cache_file));
      fclose($handle);

      // Unserialize the contents
      $currentFiles = unserialize($contents);
    }
  }

  // Sort arrays before comparison
  sort($currentFiles, SORT_STRING);
  sort($ftpFiles, SORT_STRING);

  // Perform an array diff to see if there are changes
  $diff = array_diff($ftpFiles, $currentFiles);
  if(count($diff) > 0)
  {
    echo "1";//New file/deleted file
  }
  else{
   echo "0";//nothing new
}

  // Write new file list out to cache
  $handle = fopen($cache_file, "w");
  fwrite($handle, serialize($ftpFiles));
  fflush($handle);
  fclose($handle);
}
else {
  echo "Could not login to {$host}\n";
}

// Close Connection
ftp_close($conn);
?>
```

Comment: What isn't working as expected?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

just change

`setTimeout(Update(),timeoutPeriod);`

to

`setTimeout(Update,timeoutPeriod);`

`setTimeout` takes the function reference as the first parameter while you were passing the function call. You dont need the `setInterval` here as on receiving '0' you are already calling the refresh function.

Answer (score 1):

You need to pass function reference to [setTimeout](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/WindowTimers/setTimeout), also need to use [setInterval()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/WindowTimers/setInterval) as you need to invoke it every minute

```
function timedRefresh(timeoutPeriod) {
    setInterval(Update,timeoutPeriod);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

All you need to do is to put your function inside `$(document).ready()` and change your time out structure:

```
<script>
   $(document).ready(function(){
       setTimeout(function(){
         Update()
       },timeoutPeriod);
   });
</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

> Try this one

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    setInterval(function(){ 
        //code goes here that will be run every 5 seconds.    
        $.ajax({
            type: "POST",
            url: "php_file.php",
            success: function(result) {
                //alert(result);
            }
        });
    }, 5000);
});
```